# wxLocale not working with PerlApp

Tags: perl, wxwidgets, activestate, wxperl, perlapp

When I run my wxperl app from the command line it works great but after using the PerlApp from: http://www.activestate.com/perl-dev-kit to create an executable I'm seeing the following debug alert (shown below)

[image: wxWidgets Debug Alert]

I've tried adding Locale for myFrame like so but I'm still missing something

```
use Wx::Locale qw(:default);
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
-Paul

Comment: do you call setlocale() anywhere in you program?

Comment: I do...I'll post my solution in case anyone has a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was missing:

```
use Wx::Locale qw(:default);
Wx::Locale->new( &Wx::wxLANGUAGE_DEFAULT );

use POSIX qw( setlocale LC_ALL );
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C');
```

Setting the locale to LC_ALL, 'C' resolved my issue.

-Paul